# Passing parcelable array in Android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

**How to resolve this:**

- I have Passed A custom model as which is implementing parcelable but
  I am not able to parse the data though the data is available in
  bundle. If i cast it it will give error.
- I am trying to get the data in `Category[]`

  mBundle = new Bundle();

**Previous Fragment**

```
mBundle.putParcelableArray(LinksAndKeys.STR_ARG_KEY_CATEGORIES,categories);
                fragment = new FrgCategories();
                fragment.setArguments(mBundle);
                fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FrgCategories.class.getSimpleName());
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, FrgCategories.class.getSimpleName());
```

**Current fragment**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should get data from your bundle not from Activity.getIntent();

instead of this

```
categories = (Category[]) getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(LinksAndKeys.STR_ARG_KEY_CATEGORIES);
```

try like this,

```
categories = (Category[]) bundle.getParcelableArrayExtra(LinksAndKeys.STR_ARG_KEY_CATEGORIES);
```